# Orientación con sql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos con títulos de cds de audio, los ordeno por artista y año pero tengo problemas al mostrar los compilados ya que en la columna artista figuran como "varios"

```
Esto me lo ordena bien
Bill Haley - The Very Best Of Bill Haley - 1995
Bill Haley - Rock Around The Clock - 1998

Y aquí me separa los volúmenes porque entre estos dos entrarían los Varios 1996,97,98
Varios - Rock Vol. 1 - 1995
Varios - Rock Vol. 2 - 1999
```

Existe en SQL un elmento como if?  por ejemplo...

```
if ( artista = Varios ) { ORDER BY nombre_disco, año }
else { ORDER BY artista, año }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, cualquier dato me ayudara para ir probando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque no haces un UNION?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

```
SELECT artista, nombre_disco, año
FROM CDs 
WHERE NOT artista = "Varios"
ORDER BY nombre_disco, año
UNION
SELECT artista, nombre_disco, año
FROM CDs 
WHERE artista = "Varios"
ORDER BY artista, año
```

Cuidado con el NOT en el primer WHERE.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Mork, el código funciona bien ahora me falta leer un poco sobre el para terminar de entender, soy algo nuevo en esto... una pregunta, se puede usar DISTINCT usando UNION?

Comment: UNION lo que hace es coger 2 consultas SQL y unirlas en un solo resultado, el único requisito es que las 2 consultas retornen el mismo numero de campos y que sean del mismo tipo. Entiendo que DISTINCT se puede usar sin ningún problema siempre y cuando retorne algo del mismo tipo que el resto de sentencias.

Comment: @Fabricio recuerda que si la respuesta te fue útil la mejor forma de agradecer es darle +1 y marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Gracias Mork por la info! y a ti BetaM por no dejar pasar la ocasión para aconsejar el buen funcionamiento

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar expresiones más complejas en la cláusula `ORDER BY`. Por ejemplo:

```
select *
from t
order by
  case when artista = 'Varios' then nombre_disco else artista end,
  año
```

El criterio de ordenamiento es una lista de expresiones. Típicamente esta lista de expresiones toma la forma de un subconjunto de las columnas de la expresión tabular (una tabla, un join, una CTE, etc.), pero también puede ser cualquier expresión que dé un resultado escalar (valores simples *ordenables*).

**Ejemplo**:

```
create table album (
  artista varchar(30),
  nombre_disco varchar(40),
  año int
);

insert into album (artista, nombre_disco, año) values
  ('Bill Haley', 'The Very Best of Bill Halley', 1995),
  ('Bill Haley', 'Rock Around the Clock', 1998),
  ('Varios', 'Rock Vol. 1', 1995),
  ('Varios', 'Swing Vol. 1', 1994),
  ('Varios', 'Swing Vol. 2', 1998),
  ('Varios', 'Rock Vol. 2', 1999),
  ('Varios', 'Swing Vol. 3', 2000);

select * 
from album
order by
  case when artista = 'Varios' then nombre_disco else artista end,
  año
```

Resultado:

```
artista     nombre_disco                   año
----------  ----------------------------  ----
Bill Haley  The Very Best of Bill Halley  1995
Bill Haley  Rock Around the Clock         1998
Varios      Rock Vol. 1                   1995
Varios      Rock Vol. 2                   1999
Varios      Swing Vol. 1                  1994
Varios      Swing Vol. 2                  1998
Varios      Swing Vol. 3                  2000
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo ejecutándose en [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a2i2EHwLr75ut45rTmtCuM/0).

Comment: Busque en varios lugares y nunca vi algo parecido, lo voy a investigar... hay un manual en español donde tenga buenas referencias por ejemplo como la pagina de php ?

Comment: @Fabricio Según lo solicitado, adjunto ejemplo.